# How do I modify the code so that it only outputs one headline from the news instead of all of them?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url='https://www.bbc.co.uk/news'
response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
headlines = soup.find('body').find_all('h3')
for x in headlines:
    print(x.text.strip())
```

The issue is that it prints out all the headlines from BBC articles, however, I just want to be able to change the code so that it only outputs the main headline or the first 3 headlines. Does anyone know how to help me out with this problem?

Comment: find_all method return `bs4.element.ResultSet`. You can treat headlines variable as any normal list so you can change it like this 
`headlines = soup.find('body').find_all('h3')[:3]` you will get only first three elemets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this.

Replace `k` with whatever number of headlines you wish to display.

##### Method-1: List Slicing

```
for x in headlines[:k]:
    print(x.text.strip())
```

##### Method-2: Using `enumerate()`

```
for idx, val in enumerate(headlines, start=1):
    if idx <= k:
        print(val.text.strip())
```

Comment: the only slight issue with this is that it has to create a new list which may be a bit memory inefficient compared to the other solution

Comment: however I just tested and timed both methods and it seems that slicing method is quite a lot faster than enumerating (at the cost of memory but its not like in this case there are going to be millions of articles and even then not that much memory should be occupied) so hard to tell which one is better, only that one is faster and the other takes up less space in memory

Comment: and never mind, it looks like the slicing method is far more superior than `enumerating` both in memory usage and speed or I made a mistake in measuring those things

Answer (score 1):

why don't you use counters

```
for counter, x in enumerate(headlines):
    if counter >= 2:
        break
    print(x.text.strip())
```

edited : thanks @Matiiss for informing me about this counter approach

Comment: you can use `for counter, x in enumerate(headlines)` and you won't need to keep track of a variable (except then change to `if counter >= 2:` or more like replace the `2` with some variable since normally it would be that)

Comment: yeah, only remember that indexes normally start from `0` and so does the `enumerate` (so you should use `if counter >= 2`), unless you specify `enumerate(iterable, start=1)`, then you can keep it as is

Comment: cool, thanks a lot